# C# Checking if remote desktop is enabled on a windows client

Tags: c#

Is there any way I can detect if remote desktop is enabled on windows xp/vista/7. I know that you can access the session information using performance counters but what I really need is a enabled/disabled flag?

```
PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Terminal Services", "Active Sessions");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to see if you're running under a Terminal server session, the easiest way is to check [SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession.aspx).  This returns true if you're application is associated with a terminal server session.

To see if remote desktop is enabled at all, just check for whether the Terminal Services service is running, using a [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, will the serviceController only show running services or show all and there status?

Comment: Service controller can be used to start/stop services + get info.  From the docs:  "Represents a Windows service and allows you to connect to a running or stopped service, manipulate it, or get information about it."  This lets you check services, even if they're not active.  Just do:   var sc = new ServiceController("Terminate Services");  bool running = (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running);